# What does ELO stand for?

Tags: rating, elo

What does the acronym ELO stand for in the context of chess, as in the ELO rating system?

Comment: Electric Light Orchestra. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bjPqsDU0j2I

Comment: plot twist : it is not an acronym.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It doesn't stand for anything at all, because **it's not an acronym**. It should be "Elo" rather than "ELO." The Elo rating system is named after the Hungarian-American physics professor (and 8-time state champion chess master) [Arpad Elo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arpad_Elo), who originally devised his rating system around 1960.

Comment: On a side note: There are predecessors to Arpad Elo's system, for example the "Ingo-Zahl" used already in 1947 in Germany. (And still being used by the german xiangqi-players for some reason …)

Comment: @BlindKungFuMaster, I'd not heard of that before. Gracias.